# Run configuration in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

When I press run, does it suppose to give me an output? Or does it only show error 0? I am taking a course in which the instructor gets an output when he presses the run option.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in Pycharm (under a normal run configuration) it will display the command used to run the program (grayed out at the top), followed by the program output in the run tab. When the program ends it will display the exit code (0 indicates it finished without any errors).

If it shows the exist code without any other output then the program just didn't print or use stdin/stderr while running. It doesn't sound like you have done anything wrong, you just need to modify your code to provide output. Your instructor was likely just running a different python script than the one you ran.